# App crashes suddenly: RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

My app worked perfectly but suddenly yesterday I received this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Iv'e tried some sulotions like clean and rebuild project and setting multiDexEnabled to true but none of them worked. Another sulotion?

Comment: `multiDexEnabled true` its a `true` or `false' in your build

Comment: true @MohammadAli